# Passing Date Datatype MM/dd/yyyy from ASP.NET to Select WHERE CLAUSE in SQL Server Datetime Datatype yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime

I have an issue to `SELECT` parameter type `Date` from my ASP.NET VB Application to SQL Server datatype `DateTime`

```
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CHECKIN) FROM VW_CHECKPOINT2 WHERE CHECKIN = @p1"
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(CHECKIN, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim reformatted As String = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but it's still no records to display even i passing a true date. what i'm doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: how does your data looks like ? Does `CHECKIN` contains date only or date + time  ?

Comment: @Squirrel my data is Date, looks like this >> 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Comment: If you leave all of your datatypes date throughout your SQL Server code and C# code, then format is irrelevant. In the database, what data type is `CHECKIN`?

Comment: my datatype CHECKIN is DateTime, my value to passed it is Date

Comment: How do you save your data in the database? If the time is included, then it will always return 0 rows. Example: If your database contains the date 07/01/2018 07:15:00 and if you compare this to 07/01/2018, it will return false and no rows will be retrieved. In your query, you can floor the value of your CHECKIN column like so: CAST( FLOOR( CAST( CHECKIN AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME). Now the CHECKIN column will only contain the Date part of your column.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b it's still no results. i have testing like this `SELECT * FROM VW_CHECKPOINT2 WHERE CHECKIN= CAST(FLOOR(CAST('07/08/2018' AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)`

i got an error `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Comment: ok all, thanks foryour reply. i have tried using `between` clause `SELECT * FROM VW_CHECKPOINT2 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CHECKIN) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'07/08/2018') AND '07/08/2018'` and everything works as i want

Comment: It should be: SELECT * FROM VW_CHECKPOINT2 WHERE CAST( FLOOR( CAST( CHECKIN AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME ) = '07/08/2018'. Also, make sure that your table contains the date '7/8/2018' for testing purposes

Comment: thanks @F0r3v3r-A-N00b your help are also works. thank you very much

Comment: Don't add _more_ casts to it!!! The idea is to not do any of that casting at all!!!

Comment: @nickmcdermaid casts will not be necessary if the data type is as you said Date. But the OP said that the data type in the database is datetime.